# ORA - 00904 - Invalid Identifier - Add 7 days to any order placed in the last week

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add 7 days to any order that was placed in the last week. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am getting an error saying that "ORDERDATE" is an invalid identifier. ORA - 00904.

```
UPDATE ORDERDETAIL
SET ORDERDATE = ORDERDATE + INTERVAL + 7
WHERE ORDERDATE = SYSDATE - 7;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
UPDATE ORDERDETAIL
    SET ORDERDATE = ORDERDATE + INTERVAL '7' DAY
    WHERE ORDERDATE = SYSDATE - 7;
```

You probably really intend something like:

```
WHERE ORDERDATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

because `sysdate` has a time component, so it is highly unlikely that you'll get a match to the exact time.  You want `>=` to get all orders in the past week.

Comment: I tried that as well and still getting the "ORA-00904: ORDERDATE: invalid identifier" error. Its calling the error at line 3 Column : 11.

Comment: @KC43 . . . Then presumably `ORDERDATE` is not in the `ORDERDETAIL` table.

Comment: If you want update all orders placed in the past week you want something like `WHERE ORDERDATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '7' DAY`. This doesn't solve the problem that there is not (apparently) a field named `ORDERDATE` on the `ORDERDETAIL` table. Based on my experience I'd expect a field named `ORDERDATE`, which applies to an entire order, to be on the main `ORDER` table, which could be named `ORDER`, or `ORDERHEADER`, or something similar.

Comment: The correct syntax (to implement the stated requirement) would have `>=` in the `WHERE` clause, not `=`. And what the OP really intends is `WHERE ORDERDATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7` - you are missing the `- 7` now.